# java scanner skipping last input

Tags: java

My program for the most part runs smoothly. Only incorrect part is the last input for the variable newsub does not work. Rather, the program skips over it and moves on. I tried to comment out the last part but then I was still not allowed to type anything. So apparently eclipse is skipping lines?? I saw a couple of posts, but when I changed the first part from keyboard to input an error was called because they viewed it as a new uncalled variable. Any help will be great! (Also I am fully aware that my program is longer than necessary) Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a long string: ");
        String lin = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter a substring: ");
        String sub = keyboard.nextLine();

        int leng = lin.length();
        System.out.println("Length of your string: " + leng);

        int leng2 = sub.length();
        System.out.println("Length of your substring: " + leng2);

        int mid = lin.indexOf(sub);

        System.out.println("Starting position of your substring in string: " + lin.indexOf(sub));

        System.out.println(lin.substring(0, mid));
        System.out.println(lin.substring((mid + leng2 + 1), leng));

        System.out.print("Enter a position between 1 and 43: ");
        int pos = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The character at position " + pos + " is " + lin.charAt(pos));

        System.out.print("Enter a replacement string: ");
        String newsub = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Your new string is: " + lin.substring(0, mid) + newsub + lin.substring((mid + leng2 +1), leng));

        keyboard.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
System.out.print("Enter a position between 1 and 43: ");
int pos = keyboard.nextInt();
keyboard.nextLine();
```

You need to eat up the new line character that is left over. If you don't your last `keyboard.nextLine()` will and never allow for user input.

This is a side-effect of `nextInt()` `nextDouble()` etc...they don't eat up the new line character.